# A notion of SDE via the martingale representation theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, martingales

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$It is well-known that differentiating stochastic processes with respect to time is usually impossible in the usual sense. For instance, a Brownian motion $W$ on a probability space $\mathbb{P}=(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ is nowhere differentiable with probability one. This makes it so that stochastic differential equations
$$\d X_t=b(t,X_t)\,\d t+\sigma(t,X_t)\,\d W_t$$
are really integral equations of the form
$$X=X_0+\int^{t}_{0}b(s,X_s)\,\d s+\int^{t}_{0}\sigma(s,X_s)\,\d W_{s}.$$

Since reading in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#Martingale_representation) that the martingale representation theorem gives a kind of derivative of stochastic processes with respect to a fixed Brownian motion and time, I've been wondering whether this might lead to an interesting notion of "stochastic differential equation".

First, here's the statement of the theorem:

> **The Martingale Representation Theorem.** Let:
>
> - $\mathbb{P}=(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space;
> - $W$ be a Wiener process on $\mathbb{P}$;
> - $\mathcal{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}_{t\geq0}$ be the filtration associated to $W$;
> - $\{M_t\}_{t\geq0}$ be a square-integrable continuous-time martingale on $\mathbb{P}$ that is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$.
>   There exists a unique $\mathcal{F}$-adapted  square-integrable process $\{\alpha_t\}_{t\geq}$ on $\mathbb{P}$ such that we have
>   $$M_t=M_0+\int^t_0\alpha_s\,\d W_s$$
>   almost surely for all $t\geq0$.

The idea stated in Wikipedia is that we may think of $\alpha$ as a time-derivative "$\alpha_t:=\frac{\d_{W}M_t}{\d_W t}$" of $M$ with respect to the Wiener process $W$.

**Question I.** Write $\dot{X}_t=\frac{\d_{W}}{\d_W t}X_t$. Are equations of the form
\begin{equation}
a(t,X_t)\dot{X}_t+b(t,X_t)=0\tag{1}
\end{equation}
interesting?

For example, the most simple such equation, $\dot{X}_t=X_t$, is equivalent to the SDE
$\d X_t=X_t\d W_t$, i.e. $X_t=\int^{t}_{0}X_s\,\d W_s$, which admits the solution
$$X_t=\exp(W_t)$$
for each $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$. This is an example of a [geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion).

What would be some other examples of equations like $(1)$ and their solutions? Is there a general theory of such equations (or can they be reduced to ordinary SDEs in general)?

**Question II.** Second (and perhaps a question on the martingale representation theorem itself), are there conditions on $X$ under which we can iterate the operation $X_t\mapsto\dot{X}_t$, so as to be able to talk about things like $\ddot{X}_t$ and equations like
$$a(t,X_t)\ddot{X}_t+b(t,X_t)\dot{X}_t+c(t,X_t)=0$$
or even higher-order ones?

Comment: I was thinking something else. The equation you wrote indeed has Ito solutions eg see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks! I've updated the question to add it as a proper example. (Also, let me remark that I really appreciated your initial comment (regardless of whether or not it applies to the question), as I didn't know about rough path theory and have found the theory really nice. Thank you once again for it!)